# Tagging Faces in Aperture 3 and syncing with Facebook tags

Tags: data-transfer, aperture, facebook

When I tag someones face in Aperture, it lets me either choose a name from Facebook (with the FB icon), or from my Address Book. Sometimes, these names may differ.

One of my issues with uploading to Facebook from Aperture is that I will tag a face (that may not even be on Facebook), and it will still tag that face when it goes up. Can you disable not syncing non-facebook faces?

Also, what happens if I have a person in my address book and friend them on Facebook? Is there a way to tag them so it works on both? As in, my wife uses her full name on Facebook, but in my Address Book its just first and last. How do I tag her in Aperture so that it matches her Address Book entry, but also automatically does it on Facebook as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a face is already duplicated (i.e., there're two faces of the same person), you can pick up (from the faces cockboard page) the 2nd face and drop into the 1st. Aperture or iPhoto will merge these 2 faces into 1.

If a face isn't already duplicated and you're trying to prevent duplication, prior to 10.7 Lion, you set the email address of the entry in Address Book to that in Facebook. Apparently, this is the field that Aperture/iPhoto uses to match up Facebook & Address Book.

For 10.7 Lion, Address Book has introduced a field called Profile->Facebook. By all looks, this looks to be the new field for matching, but Lion is too new to have confirmation from Google of my suspicion.

Comment: Have you tested this new field part? I started adding facebook and twitter profiles to address book, but haven't checked to see how this works in Lion.